# How to find the numbers connected with a number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Suppose we have two inputs `a and b` where `a` denotes the first integer and `b` denotes the second integer
for example :

```
if 
a= 1 b = 2
a=1 b=3 
a=2 b=3
```

here `1` is connected with two integers `2 and 3` and `2` is connected with one integer `3`

how I can find  this and print the result like this `{1:{2,3}, 2:{3}}`

Note: `a` is basically the first integer and `b` is the integer connected with `a`

Thanks in advance. and this is not homework.

Comment: Can you please share what you have attempted so far?

Comment: A dict with the integer as key, and a list of the "connected" integers as a list or set of values, might be a good way to store this information. In fact, your wanted output format is basically that: a dict of integer keys and set values.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz Yes i am supposed to write a function which reads two input a and b and then does this .

Comment: So the function reads the inputs and stores them somewhere? I think a few more details are needed.

Comment: @Calculuswhiz a function that reads the inputs and stores them in a dictionary. for all values of a and b. kindly have a look at the example

Comment: The downvotes are likely the result of the lack of a code attempt yourself.

Comment: Nowhere in your question or example did you mention the dictionary or the function. You just said you had two inputs that are somehow connected, which to me sounds really vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a function like this:

```
d = {}
def connect(a,b):
    if a not in d:
        d[a] = [b]
    else:
        d[a].append(b)

connect(1,2)
connect(1,3)
connect(2,3)
print(d)
```

output:

```
{1: [2, 3], 2: [3]}
```

If 'a' is already in the dictionary, it will add 'b' to the list connected to it. and otherwise a new item will be added to dictionary with 'a' as key and list with 'b' in it as value.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Thank you so much.

Comment: Your welcome. But I think for later it would be better if you be a little more detailed. Here I just had to assume that you wanted a function and dictionary.

Comment: Sorry I am just a beginner here so. Thank you for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

You need a data structure that is called a map, however in Python it is also called a dictionary.

A map stores entries consisting of one key and one value each.

As you want to store potentially multiple values for each key, you can use lists of int as values for your map.

Alternatively you can also use a multi map, however it is not part of the default Python library but there are additional libraries with this functionality.